# Storing address of address of function?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, lifetime

Does this program have undefined behavior?

```
struct Storage {
    void store(void (*&&fp)())  { fpp = &fp; }
    void call() const           { (*fpp)(); }

    void (**fpp)();
};

void f();

int main() {
    Storage s;
    s.store(&f);    // I think, the temporary variable &F is freed at the ';'
    s.call();
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask? Is there a problem you are trying to solve with this or purely academic interest?

Comment: @user4581301 They did not mean `f` to be variable, title asks about "address of address of function"

Comment: Nah. I'm parsing this all wrong. Never tried to perfect-forward a function pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is UB.

We can remove all the functions to make it simpler:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Storage {
    void store(int* && fp)  { fpp = &fp; }
    void call() const           { std::cout << *fpp; }

    int** fpp;
};

int main() {
    int i = 13;
    Storage s;
    s.store(&i); 
    s.call();
}
```

You could go even further to remove double pointer, but this should be clear as well. `fpp` is a pointer to local variable `fp` that goes out of scope immediately after constructor ends. Dereferencing that pointer is UB.

For additional proof, your original code triggers AddressSanitizer errors: https://godbolt.org/z/ba4vEbznb